# Как используя needle послать GET запрос c username, password и несколькими cookie-значениями?

Tags: javascript, cookie, сессия

Мне пока неудается написать работающий код по отправке GET-запроса к Login-страничке на сайт написанный на PHP. Вот примерно то, что хочу получить:

```
const needle = require('needle'); // npm install needle

static async login(mainPageUrl, username, password) {
    try {
        const options = { 
            username, 
            password,
            cookies: {
                'PHPSESSID': '6gb9es55q7vpjm3djv3upluse4',
                'CookieDateVi[viid]': '2000577'
            }
        };
        const response = await needle('get', url.resolve(mainPageUrl, 'login.php'), options); // [ERR]
    } catch (error) {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

При запуске в VSСode под отладчиком в строке `[ERR]` получаю ошибку:

```
(node:7440) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Login error. TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'PHPSESSID' in undefined
    at Function.login (c:\Projects\javascript-workspace\Finder\site.js:30:19)
```

Как правильно выполнить GET-запрос с помощью needle послав при этом имя пользователя, пароль и несколько cookie-значений?

Comment: А если попробовать передать `options` третьем параметром? https://www.npmjs.com/package/needle#needlerequestmethod-url-data-options-callback

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko: Поправил свой вопрос. Добавил ошибку, которую получаю

Comment: Вы попробуйте **ВНИМАТЕЛЬНО** прочитать документацию https://www.npmjs.com/package/needle#needlerequestmethod-url-data-options-callback. Обращаю ваше внимание на `needle.request(...)`.